# The function "triplequad" doesn't return the right volume (Octave/Matlab)

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to get the volume under a profile by using Octave. I have built a simple model for this:

```
function F1 = f_x(x)
  F1 = x-1;
endfunction

function F2 = f_y(y)
  F2 = y;
endfunction

function F3 = f_z(z)
  F3 = z;
endfunction

f_xyz = inline('f_x(x).*f_y(y).*f_z(z);', 'x', 'y', 'z');
Volume = triplequad(f_xyz,0,3,0,3,0,4)

x = 1:1:2;
y = 1:1:2;
z = 1:1:2;

f_plot=f_x(x).*f_y(y).*f_z(z)';

%Lines for plotting the 3D plot    
tx = linspace (0, 3, numel(x))';
ty = linspace (0, 3, numel(y))';
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (tx, ty);
tz = f_plot;
mesh (tx, ty, tz);
```

which gives a plot that looks like in the picture below:
[image]
I am using the [triplequad](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Functions-of-Multiple-Variables.html#XREFtriplequad) function (which works also on Matlab) to get the volume under that profile, but it doesn't look like it works. The function return a volume of 54 units, which is not really true. Calculating the volume of a parallelepiped using the full dimensions gives 36 units (3 x 3 x 4), which proves that it calculates it wrongly. The questions is... what am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't "triplequad" give the right volume?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question. This to prevent any existing answers here becoming invalid. If you have questions regarding the answer, e.g. something is not clear, leave a comment below that answer asking the answerer to elaborate. If you have a new question, please post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding the dimensionality of your problem. You're dealing with a 4D function:

```
f = @(x, y, z) (x-1).*y.*z;
```

You have a value returned by `f` (i.e. the dependent variable) determined by a set of 3 independent variables, thus a 4D function. You have to talk in terms of [*hypervolume*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypervolume) instead of volume in this case, since volume is a 3D measurement. The [`triplequad`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Functions-of-Multiple-Variables.html#XREFtriplequad) function will evaluate a triple integral of `f` over a given set of ranges for the independent variables, giving you the hypervolume:

```
>> triplequad(f, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4)  % Integrate over 0 <= x <= 3, 0 <= y <= 3, 0 <= z <= 4

ans =

  53.999999999999986  % Just shy of 54
```

Your visualization of a 3D surface doesn't make any sense, and is leading you astray in thinking that the result is wrong.

**NOTE 1:** In MATLAB, the function [`triplequad`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triplequad.html) appears slated for deprecation in a future release, so you should use [`integral3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral3.html) instead. It also appears to give more accurate results:

```
>> integral3(f, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4)

ans =

    54
```

**NOTE 2:** In regards to your comment, the function `f(x,y,z) = 1` is constant and has no dependence on `x`, `y`, or `z`. A triple integral over this function is the equivalent of computing the volume of the area over which you're integrating (`3*3*4 = 36`) multiplied by the constant function value (which is just 1 in this case). You can confirm it like so:

```
>> f = @(x, y, z) ones(size(x));
>> triplequad(f, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4)

ans =

    36
```

**EDIT:** Regarding your follow-up problem, I actually get an error when trying to run that example in R2016b, so I'm not sure how you got it to work (although the resulting value is correct):

```
>> V = triplequad(h_xxyy,0,3,0,3,0,15)
Error using inline/subsref (line 14)
Too many inputs to inline function.
```

The problem is that `triplequad` is used to perform *triple* integrals over functions of 3 variables, but your function only has 2 inputs (`x` and `y`). When calculating the volume under a function of 2 variables, you only need to integrate over those 2 variables, so you should be using the MATLAB function [`integral2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) instead (or [`dblquad`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Functions-of-Multiple-Variables.html#index-dblquad) in Octave):

```
>> f = @(x, y) x.^2.*sqrt(y);
>> V = integral2(f, 0, 3, 0, 3)

V =

  31.176914536244894
```

Note that `f` has no `z`-dependence, so `f(x, y)` is constant with respect to `z` (i.e. for a given `x` and `y`, it always returns the same value regardless of `z`). As a result, if you were to perform a third integration over the `z` dimension it would be the same as multiplying the result by the integration range:

```
>> V*15

ans =

  467.6537  % Same result you got from triplequad
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice and informative answer. I followed https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Multiple_integral.html, where f(x,y,z) = 1, but now that you mention, it makes sense with the hypervolume. Is there any way to verify the number given by *triplequad*? Maybe geometrically?

Comment: @Notabrightperson: I added a note that I *think* addresses your comment.

Comment: I have learn a lot from this and I thank you. I now have a better understanding of the dimensionality of the functions, I guess. At least it is easier to understand what I'm doing now. But I have built another simple example and it still doesn't give the right number for the volume. I have added an EDIT for this.